# Lime Survey - How to get the value of the custom field of survey-questions?

Tags: yii, field, survey, limesurvey

Lime Survey provides Code, question, Help and other fields while creating question of a Survey.

I have created one custom field called Weighting for a question in a Lime Survey.

Now, I want to access the value of this field and want to use the value of this field in final score calculation of a survey.

We can access the fields of the questions with Qcode.question, Qcode.code etc.

But, while i use Qcode.weighting , I am not able to access the value of weighting of a question.

How, can i get the value of this custom field which i have created ?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use {{Qcode.NAOK}}, because the custom field is not an assessement. That uses the value of the que